# How can I resolve the "No Font Name" issue when importing fonts into R using extrafont?

Tags: r, extrafont

I have a folder on my Windows desktop (`C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts`) which contains fonts that I would like to import into R using `extrafont`.

When I try to import the fonts using

```
library(extrafont)
font_import(paths = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Fonts", prompt=FALSE)
```

I receive the error message

```
Scanning ttf files in C:/Users/me/Desktop/Fonts ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\arista-light.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\facebook-letter-faces.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\Guardian-EgypTT-Text-Regular.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\pico-black.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\product-sans.ttf : No FontName. Skipping.
Found FontName for 0 fonts.
Scanning afm files in C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/extrafontdb/metrics
Warning messages:
1: In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/Rttf2pt1/exec/ttf2pt1.exe" -a -G fAe "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\arista-light.ttf" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgbdTh/fonts/arista-light"' had status 1
2: In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/Rttf2pt1/exec/ttf2pt1.exe" -a -G fAe "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\facebook-letter-faces.ttf" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgbdTh/fonts/facebook-letter-faces"' had status 1
3: In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/Rttf2pt1/exec/ttf2pt1.exe" -a -G fAe "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\Guardian-EgypTT-Text-Regular.ttf" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgbdTh/fonts/Guardian-EgypTT-Text-Regular"' had status 1
4: In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/Rttf2pt1/exec/ttf2pt1.exe" -a -G fAe "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\pico-black.ttf" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgbdTh/fonts/pico-black"' had status 1
5: In system2(ttf2pt1, c(args, shQuote(ttfiles[i]), shQuote(tmpfiles[i])),  :
  running command '"C:/Users/me/Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/Rttf2pt1/exec/ttf2pt1.exe" -a -G fAe "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Fonts\product-sans.ttf" "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOgbdTh/fonts/product-sans"' had status 1
```

Based on this I have two questions:

1. How can I overcome the `No FontName. Skipping.` issue?
2. What are the warning messages trying to tell me and do I need to be concerned about this?

I would appreciate any help, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/32) resolve your issue? Not sure since seems to be for Macs.

Comment: @caldwellst Thanks for pointing that out. I came across that thread but given that it is for Macs I didn't find anything useful apart from the link to the Rttf2pt1 package. Also that thread is 7 years old, so I reckon that something might have happened since then.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

As it was mentioned by @Moritz Schwarz, the problem is [traced to `Rttf2pt1`](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/32).

According to a solution proposed [here](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/88#issuecomment-890426514), downgrading it to 1.3.8 will fix the problem:

```
library(extrafont)
library(remotes)
remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")
extrafont::font_import()
```

Comment: Amazing!! This solved the problem! Thank you so much! I am really angry at them that they release such a damn beta. Damn new versions! And my GIS scripts also totally failing under R 4.x.x...

Comment: So much faster to import than getting the No font name message too!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. are there any other methods?

Comment: @MelanieBaker You might want to follow the corresponding issues at extrafont's GitHub repository; e.g. https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/88 and https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/32

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to make some modifications.  I had to install the latest version of rtools.  Then after installing Rttf2pt1, I had to restart R.  Finally, I had to specify a path in the last step: `font_import(paths="C:/Windows/Fonts")`

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same problem with one of my font files - the error always occurs in the `Rttf2pt1` executable.

I created an [issue on the GitHub page for the package](https://github.com/wch/Rttf2pt1/issues/10) - let's see if they can come up with a fix for this.

In the meantime, you can fix the issue though:

It seems to me that the origin of the error comes from a failure in the `.ttf` file. Navigate over to [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/) and download the open-source software. When installed, open your `.ttf` file and resave it as a `.ttf` using the *Generate Fonts...* option in the *File* menu. You might get a message that warns you that there is something slightly wrong with the font - you can review it if you like, but I went ahead and clicked *Generate* anyway.

Then you use the new `.ttf` file for your `ttf_import()` and you are good to go!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Moritz! I no longer have the need to use custom fonts in R but I trust that other users will find it useful. Hopefully they can find a fix for this!

Comment: nothing except this solved my long-lasting problem!

Answer (score 6):

(Writing in March 2022 from a Windows 10 machine...)

Instead of using `extrafont`, use the new package `showtext`.
(https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html).

Comment: How do you download fonts with this? Like just standard ones.

Comment: Yes. Look at the documentation. It's quite concise.

Comment: Big caveat with using `showtext`: This will convert text to polygons which means you will lose the ability to edit any text in post-processing (e.g. in Illustrator, Inkscape, etc.). Here are the details on [how `showtext` works](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html#how-showtext-works).

Comment: this is quite useful for my case, I can use any font as I wish with `font_add_google()`. thanks a lot for highlighting this package!