# Calibri font on Mac in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I am on Mac and need to use Calibri font for all ggplots, but i cannot make it work with either `extrafont` or `showtext` packages:

```
font_import(prompt = FALSE, pattern = "calibri")
```

returns

```
Scanning ttf files in /Library/Fonts/, /System/Library/Fonts, /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental, ~/Library/Fonts/ ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

and with `showtext`

```
list_of_fonts <- as.data.frame(font_files())

grep(pattern = "Calibri", x = list_of_fonts$family, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

i get

```
character(0)
```

I use Calibri in Word with no issue, but how to get it to use with ggplot?

```
theme_set(theme_minimal(
  base_family="Calibri"
))


In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Calibri"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**

The issue seems like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204259/how-can-i-resolve-the-no-font-name-issue-when-importing-fonts-into-r-using-ext) that you need to downgrade the `Rttf2pt1` package like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)
library(extrafont)
library(remotes)
remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")
extrafont::font_import()

theme_set(theme_minimal(
  base_family="Calibri"
))
ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = class)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Option 2:**

Another option may be downloading the [`calibre.ttf`](https://github.com/jondot/dotfiles/blob/master/.fonts/calibri.ttf) file and placing it in your library fonts folder on Mac. You can check this using `font_paths()`. After that you can import it like this:

```
font_import(paths = "/Library/Fonts", pattern = "calibri.ttf")
```

You can use the following code to check if the font is on your machine:

```
list_of_fonts <- as.data.frame(font_files())
grep(pattern = "Calibri", x = list_of_fonts$family, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

---

Please note: I am also using Mac.